# Разные типы данных в активности

Tags: java, android, activity, kotlin

Есть приложение, в котором отражается лента новостей. Если кликнуть на неё, то открывается конкретная новость. С лентой всё ясно, обычный recyclerView. Но активность, которая открывается после клика - почти всегда другая.
Я могу понять, если в одной новости 1 картинка и текст, а в другой 2 картинки и текст. Но в этой ситуации, в одной новости может быть 1 картинка и текст, а в другой 5 картинок, видео, ссылки на твиттер и т.п.. Подскажите, что искать, т.к. я вообще не понимаю, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Искать **что**? В чем проблема?

Comment: Что сделать, чтобы можно было показывать разные активности. Не создавать же миллион активностей. Т.е., как реализовать это вообще.

Comment: Если у вас апи возвращает к примеру Json. Там может быть и 20 полей. Дата, картинка , ссылки, текст итд. На первой активити показываете к примеру заголовок и фотку. По клику на rv открываете вторую активность и там выводите любую другую информацию., Что тут непонятного то?

Comment: Все, я понял, спасибо. Мне надо было знать, что я в правильном направлении думаю. Спасибо.